# Can't uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, installation

I have encountered the error on SQL Server 2008 R2 where Report Builder 3 fails to load with error

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ComponentLibrary.Controls.dll, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

As described in [this SQL Release Services blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/report-builder-of-sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-3-does-not-launch), this problem should be fixed by uninstalling SP3, uninstalling SP2, then re-installing SP3.

However I can't seem to uninstall SP3. When I navigate to Programs and Features -> View Installed Updates, click on SQL Server SP3, and choose Uninstall, I get a wizard window that looks like this:

[image: wizard screen shot]

There is no way to proceed. How do I move forward with this issue so that my users can get back to using Report Builder?

Comment: Even if you select mssqlserver, it does not allow you to uninstall ?

Comment: It mgiht be hard to see, but those checkboxes are diasbled - clicking on them doesn't do anything :(

Comment: Run [Discovery report](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2013/06/13/sql-server-2012-discovery-report-determining-what-sql-server-components-are-installed.aspx) and add the screenshot into the question. Did you tried uninstalling SP from command prompt.

Comment: Have not tried the command prompt. Will post a screenshot of the discovery report as soon as I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an older post, but to save anyone else a headache...

You will only be able to remove SP3, if you have already removed all other patches that have been applied since the SP3 install, you can do this via Windows Programs and features -> View Installed Updates, and checking all patch versions greater than the one for SP3.

Comment: Graham, I'm no longer in a position to verify your answer but I'll accept it and I appreciate you adding information!